# Prepared statements without using get_result()

Tags: php, mysql

My webserver does not have `mysqlnd` API extensions so I can't use it and would like to do the workaround.

Current gives error:

```
  $postid = $_GET['p'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $postid);

  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  while($postRows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $posts[] = $postRows;
  }
```

Workaround:

```
  $postid = $_GET['p'];

  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $postid);

  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->bind_result($post_id, $post_submitter_id, $post_title, ... [etc]);

  while($stmt->fetch()){
    $posts[] = $postRows; // ????
  }
```

How do I still create the array `$posts` in the new workaround?

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` with `bind_result` as the column order is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

This link privides an example of looping through a result set. You could do something like this.

```
$stmt->bind_result($post_id, $post_submitter_id, $post_title, ... [etc]);

while($stmt->fetch())
{
     $posts[] = [
         'post_id' => $post_id,
         'post_submitter_id' => $post_submitter_id,
         ...
     ];
}
```